# Is there a different way to make a pygame window fullscreen on start?

Tags: python, pygame

I know that the `pygame.FULLSCREEN` flag on `pygame.display.set_mode()` creates a window in fullscreen, but it loses the functionality of the "x" button in the corner and button to exit full screen. When I create the window using `pygame.RESIZABLE` I am able to manually enter full screen and I can still hover to the top of the screen to press the button exit full screen, unlike when `pygame.FULLSCREEN` is used. What I want is to have the window start on the fullscreen mode achieved when manually entering fullscreen with `pygame.RESIZABLE`.

I cannot make the size of the window `(0, 0)` because I need to use `pygame.SCALED` as well.

I am on a Mac if that makes a difference.

Comment: `DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.RESIZABLE)` does it work? This is creating full screen window with close button for me.